# Having trouble with multiple handlers in Android

Tags: java, android

So, I have an activity with a handler.

```
private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()

    {
        if(LiveAPI.getStatus() == 1){
            matches = LiveAPI.getMatches();
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
            LivePage.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 5000);
    }

};
```

Here I get some data and update my list with it. It works.

When I click on an item of my list, this functon is called

```
   private void showLiveMatch(int position) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LiveMatch.class);


        i.putExtra("match", matches.get(position));
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

My new activity appears, wich also contains another handler:

```
private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()

        {
            if(LiveAPI.getStatus() == 1){

                match = LiveAPI.getMatch(match.getId());
                displayCommentaries();
            }
            LiveMatch.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 5000);
        }

    };
```

Sometimes this works as I want.
But in some cases it seems like in second activity is still called       `LiveAPI.getMatches()`     from the first handler rather than    `LiveAPI.getMatch(match.getId());`

Every function displays a console text, and that's how I figure it out what function is called.

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you post either `m_Runnable` (from `LivePage` or `LiveMatch`), it does its stuff and then schedules itself to run in 5 seconds. Basically, each time you start one with a click, it creates an infinite loop. Enough clicks and you will have the logic for each of these running constantly. (That is, unless you have some other code that periodically calls `mHandler.removeCallbacks(m_Runnable);` that you haven't shown us.) Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, it's hard to recommend how to fix this, but you should somehow avoid creating these kind of infinite loops.

Be aware that all handlers you create on the UI thread simply feed `Runnable` objects into the (single) `MessageQueue` for the thread. So there's no such thing as something being called from one handler or another.

Comment: LivePage activity displays live sport scores for multiple games, and the data need to be refreshed periodically. LiveMatch activity displays live information about a single match. LiveApi.getMatch(matchId) is called and  information is updated. The problem is that in some cases LiveApi.getMatch() is not called and my info is not updated

Comment: @UnguruBulan - that sounds like a different problem from what you described in your post. Or maybe not. As I said, unless you stop the loop, the calls to `LiveAPI.getMatches()` will continue to occur every 5 seconds, even after you've started the loop that calls `LiveAPI.getMatch()` every 5 seconds. Could that explain what you're seeing? Without knowing what those two methods do, is it possible that calling `getMatches()` interferes with calls to `getMatch()`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I used `mHandler.removeCallbacks(m_Runnable);` when I switch to second activity, and `this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable,5000);` when a resumed the first one. Now it;s working. Thanks again

Comment: @UnguruBulan - Good to hear. just be aware that if you call `removeCallbacks` on a non-UI thread and the callback happens to be running (on the UI thread) at that moment, it will reschedule itself anyway. So if that's a possibility, you might want to use a `synchronized` block to exclude that possibility and/or use a `boolean` flag variable that the call-back can use to signal when it should not reschedule itself.